# What does this disconnected arrow mean on gitk?

Tags: git, gitk

What's the meaning of the blue disconnected arrow?
Note, it happened after I added a remote head and did `git fetch`.

[image]

...

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The arrow indicates a connection which gitk did not have enough space to draw. The amount of horizontal space used to draw connections is limited in order to improve readability.

Comment: So what do I have to do to see the missing connectivity anyway?

Comment: Got to: Edit -> Preferences. Increase Maximum graph width (lines, % of pane) as needed.

Comment: I put the max graph width lines at 200 and the % at 99 and I still get the arrows :/